# What are the advantages and disadvantages of creating a /usr partition for a desktop environment (16.10)?

Tags: partitioning, 16.10

I have 25 GB root partition (in addition to separate /tmp, /var, /swap, and /home partitions), and was wondering what I would gain/lose by splitting those 25 GB into a 15 GB /usr partition and a 10 GB root partition (or some other distribution)?

Comment: How come? I followed recommended guidelines somewhere, I think Kali's guided partition scheme.

Comment: What I'm asking is the detriment of the separate /var partition? Currently, I kind of need that one, because I have a small SSD, and so I placed /var on the HDD. If you help me understand the reasoning, I can discern the best course of action for my particular situation.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't I just format /var for the reinstall?

Comment: @muru: Question reworded, does it qualify for reopening?

Comment: Not really, in my view, because the advantages or disadvantages are open to debate and discussion due to varying opinions on whether to create it or not.

Comment: Actually, these two have the answer:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/516353/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-mounting-various-directories-on-sep#516371

and 

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685/why-put-things-other-than-home-to-a-separate-partition

Answer (score 1):

I would advice not to spread your system directories over more than 1 disk. You are creating more points of failures: if your HDD dies you can not boot your system. If your HDD is slow to boot the system might reach the mounting, not see /usr or /var and crash. If your SSD dies you can not boot and /usr and /var become useless.

Besides all that: the HDD will kill your boot time.

I myself would keep the system on /, maybe create a /home/ on it and put all your user data on the HDD (you can easily change the directories in /home/$USER/ to a data partition. Makes it easier to maintain, and makes it also easier to backup (all you need to backup is the data partition).

Mind though, this is regarding a desktop. For a server version that has a website, a dataserver, a mailserver or something similar it might be smart to put /var on a different disk (since we are talking about userdata in /var) or at least set it up such that the user data is (also) on the HDD.

Comment: Hmm, let me see if I understand you correctly: put everything in the SSD, then change ~/home to a different disk? How big should the system partition be? I'm dual booting with W10, which is why space is cramped. And how can I do what you describe, about moving ~/home to a data partition?)

Comment: Ah, do you mean symlinks for the 2nd part?

Comment: no, check `~.config/users-dirs.dirs`, just the dirs in /home/ to a data part  ;) system: 25Gb is more than enough.

Comment: I tried editing the file, and now all my content just gets plopped into the desktop. Basically,

Comment: According to http://askubuntu.com/questions/48446/how-to-make-permanent-change-to-config-user-dirs-dirs, the paths are relative to the home directory. When I tried setting it to /media/$path/downloads, it gets reset. So... back to /home in a different partition?